# Как работает v-html?

Tags: vue.js

Подскажите пожалуйста, на простом примере, как работает директива **v-html** ?
В документации читаю, но не могу до конца понять...

Comment: значение сетится в поле `innerHTML` без каких-либо обработок

Comment: А можно пожалуйста написать пример ? Я понимаю концепцию, не понимаю как написать на практике. Не могли бы написать простенький код ?

Comment: А можно пожалуйста написать пример ? Я понимаю концепцию, не понимаю как написать на практике. Не могли бы написать простенький код ?

Comment: `<div v-html="сюда передать html-строку"></div>`